# Toggle Between UIBarButtonSystemItem.Play and UIBarButtonSystemItem.Pause in Swift

Tags: iphone, swift

I'm learning Swift, my project is make a simple music player, I'm trying to toggle between `UIBarButtonSystemItem.Play` and `UIBarButtonSystemItem.Pause`, but all what I got across 30 minutes of searching is this [toggle between UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay and UIBarButtonSystemItemPause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068629/toggle-between-uibarbuttonsystemitemplay-and-uibarbuttonsystemitempause), but it's written on Objective-C, I don't know anything about Objective-C.

What's the correct way to get this?

Comment: I'm not sure if that way is correct on swift, maybe is there any specific way to do it on swift?

Comment: Probably solved already, but u can find the solution over here: [enter link description here][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27831306/uibarbutton-not-changing

Comment: I have fixed it on another way, but i think i can use this one in another project, thanks.