# UIBarButton not changing

Tags: swift, uibarbuttonitem, uibarbuttonsystemitem

```
@IBOutlet weak var playStopButton: UIBarButtonItem!
var playStopArray = [UIBarButtonSystemItem.Pause, UIBarButtonSystemItem.Play]
var index = 0

@IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!
@IBAction func playButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    println("pressed")
    playStopButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: playStopArray[index], target: self, action: "startMusic:")
    println("here")
    if index == 0 {
        index = 1
    }
    else {
        index = 0
    }
}
func startMusic() {
    println("test")
}
```

I expected the bar button to change to the pause symbol, but with no luck. It prints both "pressed" and "here" but "test" does not work. Why is the image not changing?

Comment: Do you call startMusic() anywhere?

Comment: Is playStopButton nil when you go to do the assignment?

Comment: I don't think your approach is right here. You don't need to change the outlet. Your IBAction sends a sender parameter. Simply use sender.setTitle(_:forState: .Normal) to change the text on the button.

Comment: I don't want to change the text -- I want to make the symbol different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is wrong.

In the following line,
`playStopButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: playStopArray[index], target: self, action: "startMusic:")` 
you are actually creating a new instance of `UIBarButtonItem`. This button is not actually added into the view. Instead of adding the `UIBarButtonItem` through Interface Builder. You can create it programmatically.

Read this question for more information.
[toggle between UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay and UIBarButtonSystemItemPause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068629/toggle-between-uibarbuttonsystemitemplay-and-uibarbuttonsystemitempause)

```
var playButton:UIBarButtonItem!
var pauseButton:UIBarButtonItem!

func setup()
{
    playButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Play, target: self, action: "startMusic:")
    pauseButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Pause, target: self, action: "stopMusic:")
}

func startMusic:(button : UIBarButtonItem)
{
     self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = pauseButton // Switch to pause.
     //Other code.
}
func stopMusic:(button : UIBarButtonItem)
{
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = playButton// Switch to play.
    //Other code.
}
```

Comment: How would I do this in Swift?

Comment: do you have a toolbar or navigation bar?

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would I do this for a toolbar?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078597/how-to-programmatically-replace-uitoolbar-items-built-in-ib

Answer (score 2):

Here is my approach in Swift

```
func configureBars() {
  isPlaying = false
  // UIToolbar
  let pickBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Search,
    target: self,
    action: "pickSong")
  let playBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Play,
    target: self,
    action: "playPause")
  let pauseBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Pause,
    target: self,
    action: "playPause")
  let leftFlexBBI = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .FlexibleSpace,
    target: nil,
    action: nil)
  let rightFlexBBI = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .FlexibleSpace,
    target: nil,
    action: nil)
  playItems = [pickBarButtonItem, leftFlexBBI, playBarButtonItem, rightFlexBBI]
  pauseItems = [pickBarButtonItem, leftFlexBBI, pauseBarButtonItem, rightFlexBBI]

  toolbar.items = playItems
}
```

visit http://www.raywenderlich.com/36475/how-to-make-a-music-visualizer-in-ios
or you can check out my Github https://github.com/Charles-Hsu/MusicVisualizer